# Replace text in multiple tables and fields in MySQL

Tags: mysql, replace, field

I'm attempting to replace particular text strings in multiple tables and fields.  I have code to do it for one field in one table, but I don't want to duplicate my efforts (since I have many strings I'd like to replace).

Here's my code for one field in one table:

```
UPDATE `phpbb3`.`phpbb_posts`
SET `post_subject` = REPLACE(`post_subject`,'string-to-be-replaced','replacement-string')
WHERE ( `post_subject` LIKE '%string-to-be-replaced%' )
ORDER BY `phpbb_posts`.`post_time` DESC
```

How do I write a command to replace text in both the phpbb_posts.post_subject field and the phpbb_topics.topic_title field?

(Do I need the WHERE or ORDER, since phpMyAdmin doesn't show the results of an UPDATE anyway?)

Comment: You don't need the `ORDER BY` clause, but I'm not sure why you wouldn't need to use a `WHERE` clause because of phpMyAdmin. `UPDATE` queries without a `WHERE` clause affect *all* rows in the table, so they're generally a bad idea. In this specific instance it may not matter much, because MySQL will be using the `replace` function to look for `string-to-be-replaced` and only replace this in any matching rows. But generally, a `WHERE` clause is the most important thing of an `UPDATE` query. You don't want all of your users' passwords to be changed because one user changed his password.

Answer (score 2):

You can't update multiple tables in one statement, however, you can use a `transaction` to make sure that two `UPDATE` statements are treated together. You can also batch them to avoid a round trip.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE phpbb_posts
SET post_subject = REPLACE(`post_subject`,'string-to-be-replaced','replacement-string')
WHERE ( `post_subject` LIKE '%string-to-be-replaced%' )
ORDER BY `phpbb_posts`.`post_time` DESC

UPDATE phpbb_topics
SET .topic_title = <something>
WHERE <column> = <something>

COMMIT
```

Comment: You probably meant to write "can't" :)

Comment: @Daan - Corrected it. Thanks for spotting it and reporting it.